# Cypress click on button on same line with the text element

Tags: cypress

I'm having trouble with clicking on the button that is multiple times on the website and has the same class.
First I need to locate a specific name and click on a button that is on the same line/row.

I tried to implement the bellow but it can find the button.

```
cy.contains('user2@gmail.com')  
.parents('tr')
.find('button')
.click()
```

For example, I need to locate the name "Agranov Anton" and click on the clock icon next to it. The name changes every time.

[image]

Comment: Can you add the html of your element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The clock icon is the 2nd button, so add `.eq(1)` to pick that one

```js
cy.contains('user2@gmail.com')  
.parents('tr')
.find('button')
.eq(1)
.click()
```

You can also specify the `<tr>` element at the first step

```js
cy.contains('tr', 'user2@gmail.com')  
.find('button')
.eq(1)
.click()
```

BUT maybe the clock icon uses an `<a>` element, if so then use

```js
cy.contains('tr', 'user2@gmail.com')  
.find('a')
.eq(1)
.click()
```

Comment: You sir, are the best! :) The third option solved my problem, since it was indeed using an <a> element. Thank you a lot! :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the name Agranov Anton is a `td` element and also the `button` is the correct selector of the button that you are clicking, you can do something like:

```js
cy.contains('td', 'Agranov Anton')
  .parent('tr')
  .within(() => {
    cy.get('button').click()
  })
```